# Searching for a specific number inside of an element with multiple comma separated values?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project where I need to read an identifying number within an element that has subelements. For example if I have a list
myList = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (4,2,3)] 
I want to grab each element who's 3rd element is 3 and inject that element into another list.

```
for i in myList:
    if myList[i] == 3:
        newList.append(mylist[i])
```

I expected the new list to be filled with the correct data (each element who 3rd "subelement" is equal to 3).
I am guessing that I have to somehow iterate through each subelement in a nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do for you, assuming that you just need `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 2, 3)]` as your result.

```
myList = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (4,2,3)]
finalList = []
for e in myList:
    if e[2] == 3:
        finalList.append(e)
finalList
```

Or a one liner can be:

```
finalList = [e for e in myList if e[2] == 3]
```

Comment: @dataScience You can accept the answer here by clicking on the tick.